# How to remake Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 faster and lightweight?

Tags: 16.04

My laptop is old it has 1 gb RAM and 32 mb video memory ! When I start Ubuntu-Mate my laptop work slow and I thought maybe make ubuntu-mate faster ! How to remake ubuntu-mate for my laptop ?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu mate will need nearly more then 1 gb ram. I really doubt it is possible to speed it up.

Reference: https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/

Try lubuntu 32 bit os:

https://docs.lubuntu.net/